# Sorting a vector of pairs <int,int>

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

How to sort a vector of pairs in descending order when the pair is incr`<int,int>`using the std::sort() in STL?It should sort first with respect to the first element and then the second.

Comment: just try it and you will see it works or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `operator<` is overloaded for `pair<int,int>` so you can sort a vector of pairs just like any other vector. If you need descending order, you have two options - either sort and then call `std::reverse` to reverse the result or provide predicate for the sorting.

You can also make use of `std::greater`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<pair<int, int> > a;
    a.push_back(make_pair(1, 2));
    a.push_back(make_pair(2, 3));
    sort(a.begin(), a.end(), greater<pair<int,int> >());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I know that the sort function works in "nlogn" time.Won't the sorting and then reversing take a longer time?

Comment: Reversing is linear and thus sorting and then reversing has a complexity of `O(n*log(n) + n) = O(n * log(n))` as `n*log(n)` grows faster than n.

Comment: This was excatly what I was looking for.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use this,

```
template<class T>
struct sortFunctor: public unary_function<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int>>
{
    bool operator()(const std::pair<int, int>& First, const std::pair<int, int>& Second)
    {
        if(First.first < Second.first)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(First.first == Second.first && First.second < Second.second)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

then pass this functor as a third parameter to sort function.

Comment: This is quite complex solution having in mind `greater<pair<int,int> >` will work.